# How to correctly lock a MYSQL table in a concurrent environment

Tags: mysql, locking

I am struggling about how to grant the consistency of the following operation in this scenario: we are developing a reservation portal, where you can sign for courses. Every course has a number of direct reservations: when the available reservations are over, users can still sign but the fall in the waiting list.

So this is the situation: for example, let's imagine that a course has 15 slots available and I make my reservation. In a simple logic, as I made my reservation the system has to decide if I am in the direct reservation list (one of the 15 available slots) or in the waiting list. In order to do so, we must count if the total direct reservations is less than the total available reservations, something like this in pseudocode:

```
INSERT new_partecipant IN table_partecipants;
(my_id) = SELECT @@IDENTITY;
(total_reservations_already_made) = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_partecipants WHERE flag_direct_reservation=1;
if total_reservations_already_made <= total_reservations_available then
UPDATE table_partecipants SET flag_direct_reservation=1 WHERE id=my_id
```

The question is: how I can manage the concurrency in order to be sure that two subscriptions are managed correctly? If I have only one reservation left and two users apply at the same time, I think it's possible that the result of the COUNT operation can give the same result to both the requests and insert both the users in the list.

What is the correct way of locking (or similar procedure) in order to be sure that if a user starts the subscription procedure no one can finish the same task before the request has been completed?

*Ok, it seems we have found a solution without locking, any comment appreciated:*

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, ..., fieldN, flag_direct_reservation)
SELECT @field1, @field2, ..., @fieldN, ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable WHERE course=@course_id) > @max_part THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**UPDATE
(only for determining the subscription status, in case of subscription deletion)**

```
UPDATE corsi_mytable p1 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as actual_subscritions
    FROM mytable
    WHERE course=@course_id
)p2 
SET p1.flag_direct_reservation= CASE WHEN p2.actual_subscritions > @max_part THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
WHERE p1.id =@first_waiting_id;
```

In this way the operation is performed by only one SQL statements and the transactional engine should ensure the consistency of the operation.

Comment: There has been no activity for some time. Can you please accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't lock the table. Instead try and book a row, and if it fails, throw them on the waiting list. For example:

```
UPDATE table_partecipants SET booking_id=? WHERE booking_id IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

The `WHERE` clause here should include any other exclusion factors, like if it's the right day. If the query successfully modifies a row the booking worked. If not, it's sold out. No lock required.

The `booking_id` here is some unique value that can be used to associate this course with the person booking it. You can delete any records that aren't used due to over-booking.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you agains locking the full table for this. Go for a row lock.

You can have a separate table that has only 1 line with your reservation counter of 15, and start by updating this counter before adding new reservations.
So you are sure the lock is managed by this separate table, which enables your reservation table to be updated by any other scenario where you don't care about the counter.